# "use strict;" line in perl causing a simple print script to fail to run

Tags: perl, internal-server-error, use-strict

I installed apache and perl a few days ago and have been successful in running a few scripts, but I have not been able to get a single script to run after putting the "use strict;" line in. All I see upon adding that line is a very generic "Internal Server Error" with ZERO unique information.

Here's a script that does gives the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

print "Content-Type: text/html", "\n\n";

print "Hello World";
```

Cannot find anyone else having this problem, really puzzling me. Could it be some setting in my installation of perl or something?

Comment: It runs fine for me. Have you set execute permission for the script? Check the server error log (if you have access to it) for more info about the problem.

Comment: What's in your apache error log?

Comment: Is this necessary in windows?
Error Log shows:
[Sat May 03 02:34:14.357924 2014] [cgi:error] [pid 2840:tid 884] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : [client 127.0.0.1:53749] couldn't create child process: 720002: cookies.pl
[Sat May 03 02:34:14.357924 2014] [cgi:error] [pid 2840:tid 884] (OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : [client 127.0.0.1:53749] AH01223: couldn't spawn child process: D:/wamp/www/cookies.pl

Comment: If you're on windows, then `#!/usr/bin/perl` will not exist.  Try, `#!perl` instead.

Comment: @Miller: Perl on Windows ignores the path to the executable in the shebang line. It takes note only of any run-time options specified there. 

Ah, but I see from ikegami's comment that Apache *does* use that line!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always check the error log in situations like this.  Let it tell you what's wrong.

There are at least three likely possibilities:

1. The script is not executable, and so will not run. (unix specific)
2. `#!/usr/bin/perl` does not exist and so can't be executed.
3. Your `@INC` is messed up some how, and so `strict` cannot be found.

Your error log should be able to say if it is one of these fairly quickly.

Comment: Changing to #!perl does indeed make the code run! It was my understanding that windows ignored that line completely; it was only used by unix.

Comment: Understandable thought, there are many environmental differences between Windows and Unix.  However, Apache is going to attempt to behave the same, especially with regard to something as fundamental as the shebang.

Comment: Would I be right in assuming that "use strict;" was in fact working as expected when it stopped my scripts from working? I expected errors to appear in place of the internal server error if it was working, rather than just in the server log.

Comment: @samsmyname, Windows doesn't use it, but your web server does.

Comment: @samsmyname: `use strict` will have *no effect* on the script that you show. Neither Windows nor Perl take any notice of the path to the perl executable specified in the command line, but it seems from `ikegami`'s comment that Apache *does* use this line.

Comment: @Borodin Yes, I do some Apache development on Windows, and it does utilize the shebang.  I realize that windows cmd is different, but that's not what this question is referring to.